# Is inverse of Dirichlet convolution unique ?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We know that the Dirichlet inverse of the constant function 1 is the Möbius function.

I just want to confirm that Möbius function is the only function which is the inverse of constant function for Dirichlet convolution.

Can anyone confirm this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please only use one of the two tags [tag:number-theory] and [tag:elementary-number-theory].

Answer (score 4):

The general uniqueness of inverses (as far as they exist) in rings applies.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are two inverses of $f$. Then we have:
$$g_1 = g_1*e = g_1*(f*g_2) = (g_1*f)*g_2 = e*g_2 = g_2 $$
Using only the properties of the convolution product.